# MySql Table wise Backup and Restore

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I'm working on Mysql data backup and restore system but stuck that how to go with it.
An Option which i may think of

**Table Wise Backup Method**

Creating A Directory With Dateandtime and directoy will have one definition text file with all databases and its table names plus seperate file for each table contaning table structure and table INSERTS.

**Table Wise Restore Method**

Reading directory and definition file to Sort backups with respect to dates and table names and user can select either all tables or one specific table to restore.

I'll be using PHP for this purpose as i have to upload these backup files automatically on different servers.

**Questions**

1- Is above backup and restore method is valid?

2- Is there a way by which i can write single file for each Database but still have some way to restore only selected or all tables in database?

3- What are important points i must to keep in mind for such applications?

Please let me know if anything Ambiguous?

Comment: It's a pain to get the correct table definitions programmatically. Not to mention when using InnoDB. Don't you have access to `mysqldump`? That would make everything so much easier.

Comment: yes i do have but is it possible to restore that dump with selected tables only?

Comment: you can dump tables individually with `mysqldump`. The same for restoring. The single table restore option is a bit tricky when using InnoDB since you rely on the relationships.

Comment: @Bart: I don't think it's hard to get table definitions. There's `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one.

Comment: @siride Thanks. I just learned something as well :-) But still it's better to use the tools that work and not implementing it yourself if you don't really need too.

Comment: @Bart: quite true, unless you have specific needs.

Comment: i myself giving a read to mysqldump; Why should i write whole Dump myself let mysqldump do the trick. then my job left to work on restoring script

Comment: @Muhammad Haseeb Khan - Posted an example

Comment: For learning purposes or experimenting, any method is fine. But on live servers, you've got to pay attention to user permissions when creating/restoring backups. So you had better have a separate user created just for bakups. This is particularly true if you've got to work on a Linux server (eg: Ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mysqldump with a simple shell script. It can be extended to dump tables. It now only dumps databases.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="username"
PASSWORD="password"
OUTPUTDIR="./"
MYSQLDUMP=`which mysqldump`
MYSQL=`which mysql`

# get a list of databases
databases=`$MYSQL --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD \
 -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

# dump each database in turn
for db in $databases; do

    # skip internal databases
    if [ "$db" == "information_schema" ] || [ "$db" == "mysql" ]; then
        continue
    fi  

    # dump whole database 
    echo "$db"
    $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD \
    --databases $db > "$OUTPUTDIR/$db.sql.bak"

    # get a list of tables inside database
    tables=`$MYSQL --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD \
     -e "USE $db;SHOW TABLES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Tables_in_$db`

    # dump tables
    for tbl in $tables; do
        echo "$db.$tbl"
        $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD \
         $db $tbl> "$OUTPUTDIR/$db.$tbl.sql.bak"
    done
done
```

Comment: thanks Bart. may be i need to find the way to creat a definition for each database first

Comment: Updated the script so it fits the question better